# how to read a string from one file and check wether that string is in another file using perl

Tags: perl

I have two text files. One file with some data like

```
 hi 
 how
```

and another file like

```
L_ hello hi whats up
 N_ david
 N_ jhon
 N_ abraham
 N_ mc D  
L_ hey how u doing
 N_ david
 N_ jhon
 N_ abraham
 N_ mc D
L_ some blah blah blah
 N_ david
 N_ jhon
 N_ abraham
 N_ mc D
```

How can I take a line from the first file and check for presence of this line in the other file?

If the line is present (e.g. `hi` in my example) I need to print only that search string and the names just below that line. Consider `L_` is some identifier for line where we check for the string if the string is present in that line I want to print the name just below that line with identifier `N_` and not the other ones, while printing the identifiers `L_` and `N_` should be removed.

I am looking for advice on how to solve this using Perl.

Comment: Please take your time to improve your question (reduce the example data size, improve spelling, etc.). Additionally, why do you need to use perl for this job?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann i have given a small example which is similar to my problem my data looks even worse that this thats why i took up this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $patterns, '<', "$ARGV[0]"
    or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]:$!";
open my $data, '<', "$ARGV[1]"
    or die "Cannot open $ARGV[1]:$!";

my @patterns;
while (<$patterns>) {
    chomp;
    push @patterns, $_;
}

my $line;
LINE: while ($line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ m/^\s*L_/) {
        foreach my $pat (@patterns) {
            if ($line =~ m/$pat/) {
                print "$line\n";
                while ($line = <$data>) {
                    if ($line =~ m/^\s*N_/) {
                        print $line;
                    }
                    else {
                        redo LINE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Lee
 what you have done is good but can u remove those identifiers like N_ and L_ before those strings

Comment: @user3388427 Change `print "$line\n"` to `print (split / /, $line, 2)[1], "\n"`, and another `print()` similarly.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne'
  BEGIN{
  $x = pop;
  ($re) = map qr/$_/, join "|", map /(\w+)/ && qr/\Q$1/, <>;
  @ARGV = $x;
  }
  $b = /($re)/ and print("\n$1"),next if /^L_/;
  chomp; s/^\w+_//;
  print if $b
' file1 file2
```

output

```
hi david jhon abraham mc D
how david jhon abraham mc D
```

Comment: i am expecting the output to be like 
     hi
       David
       jhon
       Abraham
       mc D
    How
       David
      jhon
      Abraham
      mc D
that way not jus one name if you are able to find one string in the 2nd file all names under that file should be printed

Comment: @user3388427 Then you should fix the description in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be looking at the perl functions open and grep.

```
    my $datafile = "some_data_file.txt";
    my $comparefile = "data_to_compare.txt";
    open ( my $data_filehandle, "<", $datafile ) or die $!;
    my @things_to_find = <$data_filehandle>;

    open ( my $compare_filehandle, "<", $comparefile ) or die $!;
    while ( my $line = <$compare_filehandle> ) 
    {
       foreach my $thing ( @things_to_find )
       {
          print "Match found with: $line" if $line =~ m/$thing/;
          print "Next line is :", <$compare_filehandle>;
       }
    }
```

That'll pull out the lines that match the pattern, and then print the following line. I'll leave you to figure out the details of parsing each line. The perl documentation on `perlre` will help you here.